# How do i get a KeyDown event to fire from a WPF Page

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

**Goal:** From a WPF Page, I want a user to be able to press a pre-determined sequence of keys that will fire an event causing a control(button) to appear. I have looked at everything I can find for KeyDown and Keyboard.KeyDown events and they don't seem to fire the event in the code behind.

**XAML:**

```
<Page x:Class="KioskClient.Begin"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KioskClient"
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:KioskClient"

xmlns:controls="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"    
Background="Black" 
Title="SIMS Check In"
Keyboard.KeyDown="Page_KeyDown"
>

<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="Black">

<!--Since you always want the Back, Next, Cancel button to be docked to 
the bottom of the screen, put them first in the Dockpanel and dock them, 
the other objects then fill the space.-->
<controls:UniformGrid Margin="100" Rows="1"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
</DockPanel>
</Page>
```

**C#:**

private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

I know what to do once I can get the event to fire but the event is not firing. I do not want to have to focus on anything but the Page itself which I set 'this.Focusable = true;' in the constructor. Obviously, I am missing something. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: You made an under-rated (IMO) answer to this in a comment below.  I was puzzled by this for an embarrassingly long time.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Keyboard.KeyDown` instead. That should solve your problem.

```
<Window ...
    Keyboard.KeyDown="Page_KeyDown">
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Keithernet, but Keyoard.KeyDown did not work either. With further efforts, I found that the event will fire if I put the focus on a textbox. The thing is that I don't want to have to focus on anything except the page itself.

Comment: I did a complete working example using a window with no controls in it. Are you leaving anything out? What does the XAML of your window look like?

Comment: I post an example above. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: I created an app and it worked fine. For some reason it is not working on a WPF Page, but it does work on a WPF Window. I am using WPF Pages not WPF Windows in my application.

Comment: Issue Resolved:When using the Keyboard.KeyDown event, it has to be done in the parent Window, in my case is MainAppWindow. This fires any time a key event occurs in its child Pages which can then be modified to ignore or acknowledge certain key presses using Modifiers for key combos, or if/else statements for single key presses. To have key press events ignored from certain pages, use PreviewKeyDown event instead of KeyDown event. This allowed me to ignore when the key press combo occurred from other pages I did not desire.

Comment: That's great news!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I ran into this issue recently.

Basically adding focus to any of the page child components (e.g. textboxes, images ....) will solve the problem.

You can do that in code-behind:

```
 public ColorsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Image1.Focus();
    }

 private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = e.Key;
        MessageBox.Show(key.ToString());
    }
```